# How can I convert uint64 into string in Soldity

Tags: solidity

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./Strings.sol";

contract NFTTest {

   uint64 serialNum = 1;

   string public uri;
   string public uriPrefix ="abc/";
   string public uriSuffix = ".json";

function setURI() external {
   uri = uriPrefix + Strings.toString(serialNum) + uriSuffix;
}
```

But the issue is I get the error:
`Operator + not compatible with types string storage ref and string memory`

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm using the Strings.sol library.

Answer (score 1):

Openzeppelin's `String.toString()` accepts a uint of `uint256`. So before using `toString`, cast your `uint64` to `uint256`.

[image]

For example:

> variable = String.toString( uint256( numberInUint64 ));

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use abi.encodePacked to combine multiple strings

For example:

```
   uri = string(abi.encodePacked(uriPrefix, Strings.toString(serialNum), uriSuffix));
```